# SQL - return only if no result is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a survey. Users answer to questions, but they can skip them if they want.

If they skip them, then the question answer status will stay NULL.

There are a lot different surveys, all of them with different number of question.

Now, I need to select users who answered all the questions. If only one question has NULL in the answer status, then I don't return him.

The surveys, aswell as the questions, are generated with the PHP. They are not created upstream through any kind of SQL

My database looks like this:

USER (**idUser**, name)

ANSWER (**#idSurvey**, **#idUser**)

SURVEY (**idSurvey**, name, **#idQuestion**)

QUESTION (**idQuestion**, question, status)

remember it's only an exemple close to my case. This database is not optimized at all and the situation a bit weird. Please, do not mind this.

So, I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    USER U, ANSWER A, SURVEY S
WHERE
    U.idUser = A.idUser
AND
    A.idSurvey = S.idSurvey
AND
    S.idSurvey = 1
AND
    S.idQuestion IN
    (
        SELECT 
            idQuestion
        FROM 
            QUESTION Q, SURVEY S
        WHERE 
            Q.idQuestion = S.idQuestion
        AND
            S.idSurvey = 1
        AND 
            Q.status is not null
    );
```

Of course, here, SQL returns every single users who answer to at least one of the question of the survey.

I'm using SQL-Server

Can someone help me out please?

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really stop using those ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause and use an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: Totally forgot to mension! I'll go edit it! I use SQL-server

Comment: @Gordon I don't understand what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to exclude the reverse, you have written the problem as

> return only if all result are not null

Which could be stated instead as:

> return only if no result is null

That then makes it simpler and leads you to put something like this in your where clause

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  from question q
                  inner join survey s on q.idQuestion = s.idQuestion
                  inner join answer a on a.idsurvery = q.survey
                  where s.idSurvey = 1
                  and a.idUser = U.idUser
                  and q.status is null
                  )
```

The thing to note is a.idUser = U.idUser - that's a correlated value coming from the main query.

The database model posted is a bit odd since an answer is not being linked to a question but to an overall survey.

Comment: Oh yes! You're right about the model. But It is just an exemple. Real bad exemple, but still!

I'll try what you posted

Comment: Why did you selectd "1" from the question?

Comment: The 1 is arbitrary, I could of selected 'foo' for example or 'exists'